# Using Range.Replace method on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I recently came across an issue using Range.Replace method.

```
'more code here
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:D10").Replace What:="x", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart`
‘more code here`
```

On an unprotected sheet this works just as expected.  But on an unprotected sheet no changes get made, plus it stops on the next line with a 1004 error.

[image]

Also, oddly, if there is no Replace character found in the range ("x" in the example), everything proceeds normally without raising an error.

So my workaround is to unprotect/protect the sheet just before and after the Replace line.
The sheet is protected with UserInterfaceOnly = True, so I find it puzzling that the workaround is required.

I experience the same results on both xl2003 and xl 2010, running Windows 10 Pro ver 2004 build 19041.804.

So I’m wondering if something’s broken, or that’s just the way it is.

Thank you.

Comment: @FaneDuru, thanks for your reply, and that's what I am doing.  But as I said in my post, I would have thought protecting with UserInterfaceOnly = True would have made that unnecessary.

Comment: On the older versions of Excel, the UserInterfaceOnly doesn't get remembered after you close the workbook and you have to reapply it when it is reopened.  I think that has been fixed in the latest versions, but it's only fairly recently.  Would that explain it?

Comment: @SeniorMomentum No, that's not the case here, UserInterfaceOnly gets reapplied when the workbook is opened. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### Replace on a Protected Worksheet

- [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) doesn't work on a protected worksheet.
- Try the following workaround. You don't even have to unlock the cells.

**The Code**

```
Sub replaceProtectedTest()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1:D10")
    replaceProtected rg, "x", ""
    ' Or just:
    'replaceProtected ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10"), "x", ""
End Sub

Sub replaceProtected( _
        ByRef rg As Range, _
        ByVal SearchString As String, _
        ByVal ReplaceString As String, _
        Optional ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
        Dim Data As Variant
        If rCount + cCount > 2 Then
            Data = rg.Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        End If
        Dim r As Long
        Dim c As Long
        Dim cValue As Variant
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                cValue = Data(r, c)
                If VarType(cValue) = vbString Then
                    Data(r, c) = Replace(cValue, SearchString, _
                        ReplaceString, , , CompareMethod)
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
        rg.Value = Data
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "Range.Replace doesn't work on a protected worksheet".  Yes, I know that, what I was trying to find out is why it  doesn't work with UserInterfaceOnly = True.  Most things do, but this appears to be an exception.  So far I haven't come across any documentation to support this, but it appears to be the case.  While I do appreciate your suggestion for a workaround, I think mine is easier, just add a Sheets(x).Unprotect "Password:="pword" statement above, and a Sheets(x).Protect Password:="pword",UserInterfaceOnly:=True statement below the Range.Replace line.